# Error while using the replaceAll() method

Tags: java, string, character, replaceall

I have some code that looks like this:

```
str.replaceAll('$', ' ');
return str;
```

What I'm trying to do here is replace every instance of $ in my string str with a space. But I get this error when I compile:

```
incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
        str.replaceAll('$', ' ');
                       ^
```

But I'm not converting anything to string, I'm replacing a character by a space character. So why am I getting that error?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) the method you want to use is

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                String replacement)
```

so your code should look like

```
str.replaceAll ("$", "");
```

**note**

If you really need to use `replaceAll` then escape the "$" mark `\\$`

**BUT**

As in regex "$" has a special meaning (end of the String) **and** you do not have any special regex requirements then use `replace` instead

```
str = str.replace ("$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll is expecting two strings, but you are passing chars. Use " instead of '